# Writing a generic InsertData method using Dapper.Contrib and InsertAsync

Tags: dapper, dapper-contrib

I am fairly new to C# and Dapper. I am trying to write a generic Insert Data method for my project. I come from a Delphi environment so I am still finding my way around C#.

Dapper seems fairly straight forward to use but I am experiencing some challenges. I have tried every which way to get the syntax right with the following code but have been unsuccessful.

Issues seem to be around the **T** (I still quite don't understand what **T** is) and all the combinations I have tried don't work.

```
public async Task<int> InsertData<T>(T list)
{
    string connectionString = _config.GetConnectionString(ConnectionStringName);

    using (IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        return await connection.InsertAsync<int>(list);
    }
}
```

The following code does work, so where am I going wrong?

```
public async Task SaveData<T>(string sql, T parameters)
{
    string connectionString = _config.GetConnectionString(ConnectionStringName);

    using (IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
            await connection.ExecuteAsync(sql, parameters);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second code (`await connection.ExecuteAsync(sql, parameters);`) works because you are simply executing your hand written SQL statement. The method `ExecuteAsync` belongs to Dapper; NOT Dapper.Contrib. The generic `T` is used for `parameters`, not for the object you are trying to insert.

With your first code (`return await connection.InsertAsync<int>(list);`), you are actually using Dapper.Contrib; you are not writing the SQL statement by hand. Dapper.Contrib generates it for you.

Your following code seems the problem:

> ```
> return await connection.InsertAsync<int>(list);
> ```

You are passing generic parameter `<int>` to the method which does not make sense.

I have not tested this but I hope changing that line to below one should work:

```
return await connection.InsertAsync<T>(list);
```

Also, you have to make sure the generic type `T` is class by adding  `where T : class` to it.

Following generic method should serve your purpose; you need to convert it to `async` to match with your current code:

```
public void InsertData<T>(T entity) where T : class
{
    string connectionString = ....;

    using(IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        long result = connection.Insert<T>(entity);
    }
}
```

I did not understood few other parts in your code. Say `InsertData<T>(T list)`. What is `list`? Is it as single object or list of objects? If it is list of objects, `List<T> list` makes more sense. If it is single object, better you rename `list` to actual object name, say `T customer/entity/poco` etc.